# Парсинг страниц QT+JS

Tags: javascript, qt, парсер

есть код:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        connect(web, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), this, SLOT(finish()));
        web = new QWebView();
        web->load(QUrl ("https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt"));
    }
void MainWindow::finish()
{
     web->show();
     QVariant f1result =  web>page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsById(\"firstHeading\")");
     qDebug() << f1result.toString();
}
```

В консоль ничего не  выводится,  ну  если быть точнее "".
Думал  JS мб вообще в  проекте   не  активен,  написал /web->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("alert('!!!')"); - работает.
Ожидание загрузки  страницы тоже  реализовано через сигнал loadFinished.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: getElementById а не elementS, а не так ты делаешь очень много, в ботах ты дилетант

Comment: я не  просил оценивать уровень моих знаний, а по делу - не помогло

Comment: давай ты не будешь  писать глупости и оскорбления, или по делу , или 
 никак. Я в 1  посте  спросил,  что не так,  предложенный тобой   вариант не  решил  проблему,   страница все так же не  парсится.

Comment: @koshkashoshka, _"спросил что именно не так"_ - раз уж ты тут, то что помешало самому это рассказать, желательно в ответе? Вопрос тут уже есть, а если отвечать не хочется, то надо проходить мимо, а не требовать, чтобы тебя спросили.