# На чем сделать JS-парсинг большого количества WEB-страниц

Tags: javascript, парсер, scrapy, web-scraping

Добрый день!
Предположим - есть много открытых веб страниц, контент на которых меняется динамически и очень часто. Может раз в секунду.
Много - это несколько тысяч.
Задача - сделать парсинг этих страниц.
Почему именно парсинг с помощью JS ? Т.к. контент формируется скриптами. Поэтому мне видится что можно сделать для каждого типа страниц свой JS скрипт, который будет выводить JSON массив с необходимой информацией в программу-обертку, которая будет в свою очередь складывать данные в базу.
Проблема в том, что для того, чтобы просто открыть эти несколько тысяч страниц в браузере - нужно несколько сотен компьютеров.
Есть ли какие то средства, которые могут открывать ВЕБ-страницы, держать их в памяти, выполнять на этих страницах JS скрипты, получать данные из консоли, но при этом быть не такими ресурсоемкими, как обычный браузер?

Гугл дал мне некоторые наводки:

1. Парсинг страниц QT+JS
   [Парсинг страниц QT+JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/739463/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86-qtjs)
2. SCRAPY

В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал это на NodeJS. У него есть инструменты для работы с открытыми страницами и поддерживается практически полная ситмуляция браузера, т.е. движок рендерит страницу, загружает все скрипты, выполняет их и т.д. и т.п.

Ключевые слова для поиска: NodeJS, Phantom или jsdom. Я работал с парсингом сложных страниц и использовал для этого jsdom. Но он прожорлив и достаточно медленный, что логично, учитывая что мы хотим полностью отрендерить страницу и прогрузить все ресурсы.

**Но**! На несколько тысяч страниц, да еще и таких динамических (они сделаны современно, полагаю, и не оглядываются на расход памяти), вам потребуется очень много оперативной памяти (вот в хроме, например, страница потребляющая более 100мб - норма, часто и до 300 на сложных страницх). Т.е. сервер с 64гб оперативки, например. Вы разоритесь на нем) Иного пути держать открытыми все эти страницы и собирать с ним данные я не вижу.

Comment: Иван, спасибо за ответ! Сервер с 64 ГБ оперативы - это сейчас не так дорого. Давайте посчитаем: если предположить что одна страница весит 50 МБ, то 64 ГБ хватит на 1280 страниц. Соответственно для 5000 страниц потребуется 3-4  сервера. Меня бы это устроило.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел один из примеров - 70 МБ.